# Aptana Studio: A server is already running error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, aptana3

Sometimes when I boot up my computer then open up Aptana Studio for Rails, then try to start my server, I get the following error...

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
A server is already running. Check C:/Users/bob/bob_rails_demo/Course_Stats/tmp/pids/server.pid.
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
```

When I check that file metioned, I open the file and all it says inside the file is ...

> 512

Is there a fix for this?  I don't see anything else running in task manager.  BTW I am running rails 3.2.11 w/ Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is saying that PID (process id) 512 is running the server.

Go to Start -> then type `taskmgr.exe`.  Then, go to the processes tab and look for that process and kill it.  It might be a bug that it does not close the server correctly on exit.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem too, and it didn't happen before, so i believe it is some kind of bug. What I do to solve it is simply delete the server.pid at C:[pathToApp]\tmp\server.pid file before starting my server.